# In PHP 7.1 which ini file do I use?

Tags: php, apache2, ini

After installing Apache2.4 and PHP 7.1 I found there are two php.ini files one being located in `/etc/php/7.1/cli` and the other in `/etc/php/7.1/apache2`

Why is there two and which one is the correct one to use?

Comment: Do you know what "CLI" is? Look it up.

Comment: The `cli` is the command line one, the apache2 is the one you are running from the website. Run `phpinfo` from each interface and you can see what it is running to be sure.